# Getting rows from a PANDAS dataframe that fulfill (a dictionary?) of requirements

Tags: python, pandas

I want to filter rows of a pandas `DataFrame` by specifying a *variable* set of `column==value` conditions.

Let's say we have a toy `DataFrame` like this one:

```
from itertools import product
from numpy.random import rand
df = pd.DataFrame([[i,j,k,rand()] for i,j,k,m in product(range(2), repeat=3)],
                    columns=['par1','par2','par3','val'])
```

where some of the rows would look something like:

```
   par1  par2  par3       val
0     0     0     0  0.464625
1     0     0     1  0.481147
2     0     1     0  0.817992
3     0     1     1  0.639930
4     1     0     0  0.035160
5     1     0     1  0.549517
6     1     1     0  0.172746
7     1     1     1  0.855064
```

I wonder what's the best way to select some rows by specifying some 
`column==value` conditions that don't need to include all columns, nor be always the same columns or even the same number of columns. I think a `dict` would be a fairly natural way to specify the conditions:

```
conditions = {'par1':1, 'par3':0}
```

In this case any value of `df.par2` would do.

#### `df.isin()`

I'm aware of `df.isin()` with `dict` arguments together with `all(1)` [as shown in the docs](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.13.1/indexing.html#indexing-with-isin) (last block of code of the section). The problem is that the values in columns that weren't pass a criteria in the `df.isin()` call give `False`, so the subsequent call to `all(1)` gives an empty DataFrame. (A way out would be to add all the missing columns with ALL possible values as criteria, but it doesn't sound like a nice solution)

#### `df.query()`

While writing the question I came up with this other attempt. This one looks quite better: automatically building the query from a conditions `dict`.

```
df.query(' & '.join(['({} == {})'.format(k,v)
                     for k,v in conditions.iteritems()]))
```

it works as expected...

```
   par1  par2  par3       val
4     1     0     0  0.035160
6     1     1     0  0.172746
```

Still, I'm not completely convinced, I wonder if is there a more natural/proper/clear way to do it... Pandas is so huge I always have the impression I'm missing the proper way to do things... :P

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could make a Series of `conditions` and select only those columns:

```
>>> df[(df[list(conditions)] == pd.Series(conditions)).all(axis=1)]
   par1  par2  par3       val
4     1     0     0  0.937192
6     1     1     0  0.536029
```

This works because after we make the Series, it compares the way we need it to:

```
>>> df[list(conditions)]
   par1  par3
0     0     0
1     0     1
2     0     0
3     0     1
4     1     0
5     1     1
6     1     0
7     1     1
>>> df[list(conditions)] == pd.Series(conditions)
    par1   par3
0  False   True
1  False  False
2  False   True
3  False  False
4   True   True
5   True  False
6   True   True
7   True  False
```

Comment: Up-voted because I learned something! Thanks!! Still, I'm not sure it's really better than the `query` method. With the toy DataFrame in the answer I get slightly faster performance with the `Series` approach, but using a 9-column 1679616-row DataFrame with 4 conditions, the `query` method is ~15 times faster... And regarding readability, none is specially obvious, are they? :-P   
Any other consideration I'm missing? Can you convince me? (Honestly; I'm a Pandas newbie, I still have a lot to learn!)